# Как оптимизировать функцию?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть задачка https://www.codewars.com/kata/56a1c63f3bc6827e13000006

Условие:
Напсиать ф-ию `smaller`, который на вход принимает массив, и для каждого элемента входного массива определяет, сколько элементов в данном массиве, которые находятся справа, меньше его. Ответ должен быть в виде массива, где ответы в том же порядке что и элементы входного массива

Тест-кейсы:

```
console.log(smaller([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])); // [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
console.log(smaller([1, 2, 0])); // [1, 1, 0]
```

При вызове функции в качестве параметра используеться массив длинной 30000+- элементов и из-за этого код выдает ошибку Execution Timed Out (12000 ms), как бы код рабочий, но недостаточно оптимизирован, как это можно исправить?

Вот мой код:

```js
function smaller(arr) {
  let length = arr.length;
  let tempArr = arr;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    tempArr = tempArr.slice(1);
    let count = 0;
    
    for (let j = 0; j < tempArr.length; j++) {
      tempArr[j] < arr[i] ? count++ : 0;
    }
    
    arr[i] = count;
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(smaller([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]));
console.log(smaller([1, 2, 0]));
```

Comment: Напиши подробно в чём состоит задача и каков результат ожидается

Comment: и отформатируй код пжлста

Comment: прежде чем оптимизировать, нужно знать, что делает код. А этого нам не рассказали

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Засунь в beautifier и всё

Comment: @ΝNL993 тут в другом смысл...

Comment: У вас кстати `tempArr` вызывает мутацию у массива `arr`.(Вроде)

Comment: Ребят, я честное слово не могу понять условие... Почему ответ [1, 2, 0] - это [1, 1, 0]. Я ещё глянул упрощённую версию и вообще не вижу разницы со сложной версией, вроде те же данные на входе и выходе

Comment: А, кажись допёр, надо вернуть для каждого элемнета массива, кол-во элементов справа, которые меньше чем он:)

Comment: Учитывая условия задачи (и результаты который должны быть) вот всё в одной строке: `arr.map((e,i,a) => e < 2 && a[i] !== a[a.length-1] || e === 0 ? e : e -1)`

Comment: @ΝNL993 Этот код я так понимаю, что не подразумевается, что код кто-то попытается прочитать?))))

Comment: @EzioMercer именно так, ну знаете, ограничения комментариев и всё такое.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Вам кто-то запретил подробные ответы писать?)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136964/discussion-between-nl993-and-eziomercer).

Comment: Вообще-то это непростая задачка. Требует использования упорядоченного набора данных (типа построения BST на лету) или модификации сортировки слиянием (наподобие подсчёта инверсий)

Comment: @ΝNL993 вы вероятно не правильно поняли условие задачи, ваш код просто возвращает все элементы массива уменьшенные на 1, за исключением 0 и 1 в некоторых случаях)

Comment: @kost1k я определённо неправильно понял условие.

Comment: @ΝNL993
Функция smaller принимает на вход массив, а возвращает массив с таким же кол-вом элементов, но каждый элемент стал числом показывающий количество элементов массива < чем он. Например:
arr[1, 2, 0]; smaller(arr); вернет массив [1, 1, 0], т.к. arr[0] < arr[1], но > arr[2], то есть справа от элемента arr[0] есть 1 элемент, < него и в новом массиве первый элемент будет равен 1
arr[1] > чем arr[2], то есть справа от элемента arr[1] есть 1 элемент, < него и в новом массиве первый элемент будет равен 1
arr[2] - последний элемент, то есть справа него 0 элементов < него.